# Characterizing a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to characterize the following differential equation
$$x''+x=3 \cos(\omega t)$$

Well it is a second order linear differential equation and because $3 \cos(\omega t) \ne 0$ it is inhomogeneous.

But is it autonomous?

Comment: To answer this look at the definition: "A differential equation or system of ordinary differential equations is said to be [autonomous](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Autonomous.html) if it does not explicitly contain the independent variable (usually denoted $t$)"

Comment: For autonomous systems, if $x(t)$ is a solution then $x(t+C)$ is also a solution, which is not the case here (verify that).

Comment: So it is not autonomous?

Comment: @AlimTeacher What is it in the definition above you don't understand?

Comment: I understand this if $F(x(t),x'(t),x''(t),...,x^{n}(t))=0$ then it is autonomous but if $F(t,x(t),x'(t),...,x^{n}(t))=0$ then it is nonautonomous because it explicitly depends on the variable $t$. If so then I am good...

Comment: Exactly. And your ODE is on the second form.

Answer (score 0):

The homogeneous problem is $$x''+x=0$$

The characteristic equation is $$\lambda^2+1=0 \Rightarrow \lambda =\pm i$$

So, the solution of the homogeneous problem is $$x_H(t)=c_1\cos t+c_2 \sin t$$

We have to take cases for $\omega$, if it is an eigenvalus of the homogeneous problem:

- $\omega \neq 1$

  Since the non-homogenous term is $3 \cos (\omega t)$ the particular solution will be of the form $x_p(t)=A\cos (\omega t)+B \sin (\omega t)$.

  Substituting this at the differential equation you will find the coefficients $A$ and $B$ and then the solution is $$x(t)=x_H(t)+x_p(t)$$
- $\omega =1$

  Since the non-homogenous term is $3 \cos (\omega t)$ the particular solution will be of the form $x_p(t)=Ax\cos (\omega t)+B x\sin (\omega t)$.

  Substituting this at the differential equation you will find the coefficients $A$ and $B$ and then the solution is $$x(t)=x_H(t)+x_p(t)$$

Comment: But is it autonomous?

Comment: Does not seem to answer the OP's question.